# Is there a usage like "feel done" in English?

Tags: american-english

I saw a sentence like:

> "Have you ever felt done by blablablah?"

What does it mean?

Comment: I don't suppose it was "hard done by", by any chance?

Comment: I can think of a couple different things that it *might* mean, but I'd want more context besides "blablablah" before I'd venture a guess.

Comment: You might take a look at the phrases *done in* and *done for*. Whether they might work depends on *blablablah*.

Comment: I lost the website I found it from.but I found out another similar example wording like"i felt impelled to go on speaking". I think it is also about the case I mentioned above.so could you explicate it?

Comment: I can't see any connection between "felt done by" and "felt impelled to go on speaking" (other than the use of "felt").

Answer (score 1):

"done by", usually but not always in the phrase "hard done by", can mean "treated" or "used". "Hard done by" means "unfairly ill-treated". It is possible that the sentence

> Have you ever felt done by...

was using this sense, but without more context one cannot be sure of that.

(I have seen "well-done by", but not often, and "doing well by" or "doing right by" more often.)

Answer (score 0):

Done, on its own, can mean tired or exhausted.

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/done#Adjective

It can also mean prosecuted, as in "He was done for shoplifting".  This is a bit slangy, though.

But I've never seen it used as in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

"Done" has a large number of slang meanings. A lot of them could be relevant but without more context, it is hard to say.

One meaning of "done" is to be cheated, ripped off, or be robbed. (Maybe only in British English.) This could work with "feel done". So "have you ever felt done" would mean "have you ever felt cheated"

> Done (adjective): 10. *informal* cheated; tricked

[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/done)